# Efficient way to code a number within a range?

Tags: logic

If I have something like:

```
value is between 1-1000
And if value is within 1-100, output A
within 101-200, output B
within 201-300, output C
within 301-400, output D
within 401-500, output E
else, output F
```

Can this be done more "efficiently" or better than having `if` statements for each one?

Comment: Instead of within, check for less than. value<100 output a, less than 200 out b and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a mapping between value and output:

```
outputs = [ A, B, C, D, E, F, F, F, F, F]
output  = outputs[(int)((value - 1)/ 100)]
```